# Combinatorics - Classic Circular Table Problem, with a Twist

Tags: combinatorics

**Problem.** How many ways are there to arrange 6 people around a circular table with 7 seats? (Two seatings are considered the same if one is a rotation of the other.)

So, I know how to solve the classic circular table problem. There are simply $(n-1)!$ ways for $n$ people to sit around a circular table with $n$ seats. How would one attempt this, though? Please give a detailed solution.

Comment: It is the same as 7 people: 6 real and a "void".

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: 6 people with 13 seats would make more interesting case.